# css classes transition on hover not working

Tags: css, class

Below is the code for a div inside a div sliding up to 50% using a css transition. I am having a problem though with my classes and id. The CSS is correct however I can not get it working, could somebody please tell me where I have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

CSS

```
<style>
    .maincontentdiv {
        position:relative;
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        background:red;
    }
    .slideup {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        max-height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:blue;
        transition:max-height 250ms ease-in;
    }
    .maincontentdiv:hover {
        max-height:50%;
    }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="maincontentdiv">
    <div class="slideup"></div>
</div>
```

It works fine when I used div and div div instead of classes and id, but when I try to use classes and id it stops working so I dont think it would be the actual code :)

Comment: @RachelGallen It works fine when I used div and div div instead of classes and id, but when I try to use classes and id it stops working so I dont think it would be the actual code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/slideUpUsingMinHeight/

```
.maincontentdiv {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
}
.slideup {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;         /* Absolute el. loose width so... */
    bottom:0;
    min-height:0;       /* Use min- height instead */
    background:blue;
    transition: min-height 250ms ease-in;  /* target min-height respectively */
}
.maincontentdiv:hover > .slideup {  /* hover el > children selector */
    min-height: 50%;    /* and animate! */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `width`&`height`of the small div.The property `max-height` just sets a limit to the height,not defines it.

Secondly you need to hover the big div,not the small one,cause it's width and height are both 0,how can you hover it?

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qeJCn)

Hope this will do some help.;-)